# Autohotkey Confused with arrays

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

Could you please help me with this script (just a little Snippet):

```
array := [ "" ]

Loop, 12{
  array[A_Index] := aVariable
  text := array[A_Index]
  MsgBox %text%
}
```

**But the Message Box is empty, and i am 100% sure, that aVariable contains something (tested with MsgBox)**

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to `push`, it's not javascript. See [the documention](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm).

Comment: Your code is fine. It works in isolation.  the Message Box is empty because `aVariable` is unassigned.   When I give `aVariable` a string value, it displays that very string value 12 times. Your code works.  The problem is probably related to whatever you're doing with `aVariable` prior to the code block you supplied.  Either it doesn't contain what you think it contains, or "tested with MsgBox" isn't testing what you think you're testing. or you're testing  `aVariable` is in a different scope than the code you supplied.

Answer (score 1):

aVariable is empty

```
aVariable := "HELLO"
array := [ "" ]

Loop, 12{
  array[A_Index] := aVariable
  text := array[A_Index]
  MsgBox %text%
}
```